# About failsafe jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I am confusing with following code.
Are they do the same thing and all failsafe code? 
In my guess the second and third are not failsafe code. Am I right?

```
    jQuery(function ($) {

    });
    ----------------------------------

    $(function ($) {

    });
    -----------------------------------

    $(document).ready(function ($) {

    });
    ----------------------------------

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

They are all same. In jQuery, $ is a shorthand of jQuery. All the code execute when the document is ready.

```
$(function() {
    // this behaves as if within document.ready
});

(function($){
    //same as above
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the document about [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.